# Change the default fading edge color of Horizontal scroll view?

Tags: android

I am creating a HorizontalScrollView. I need to changes the Fading Edges color. 
How do I achieve this?

I have tried with the code below.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="16dp"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:overScrollMode="never" >

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

For ScrollView, you need to set

```
android:background="@color/fadingEdgeColor"
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
```

and For the LinearLayout

`android:background="@color/color"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background (will also change the fading edge color), try this:

```
android:background="@color/color"
```

If you want to change just the fading edge, you will have to override the `getSolidColor` function of your ScrollView:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getSolidColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getSolidColor%28%29)